# How to get top level 'div(s)' only in parent and exclude the nested divs inside those elements

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to retrieve only the top level 'divs' under my 'row' while excluding the nested 'div' in each. My code grabs the nested divs as well.

```
var container = $(event.target).closest('.row').children('div');
console.log(container);
```

outputs:

```
<div class="ELEMENT I WANT ONLY">
    <div class="nested element I do not want">
        <div class="nested element I do not want">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't believe I can use class as the selector because the class varies depending on the element.

My goal is to select the "row" and the first "div" underneath it so I can change the bootstrap column settings in the class for that div. The various rows have a different amount of divs that I need to modify so I need to grab more than the first if it exists.

Comment: `$("div-element").not($(".div-element").childNode())`?

Comment: That code gets any `div` that is a direct child of an element with class `"row"`. The descendents of those `div`s are part of the DOM tree, so they would naturally go along with them. If you act on the elements returned, it will only affect the `div` selected. In other words, `container.addClass('yada')` will add the `"yada"` class only to those child `div`s.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - Thanks for explanation, I was not understanding why it was returning the rest of the DOM tree and believed continuing with my code was pointless until I corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

**jQuery**

```
var container = $(event.target).closest('.row').find(':first-children');
```

or

**JS**

```
var container = event.target.closest('.row').querySelector('div');
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mike McCaughan had the correct comment. My code was fine and doing what it was supposed to do, the problem was that I misunderstood the results it displayed back to me.